# Why Fragment stay in the background?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I was wondering why my Fragment stay in the background when I switch betwwen them.

Here are the images to explain: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zO1NV.jpg

The problem seems very rare and it's talking about backstack. Can you explain this to me ?

So, here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

public FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
public FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
public Fragment FragmentToDisplay = null;
public static Context cMainActivity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    cMainActivity = this;
    displaySelectedScreen(R.id.main_layout);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    displaySelectedScreen(item.getItemId());
    return true;
}

private void displaySelectedScreen(int ItemId){
    if (ItemId == R.id.main_layout){
        FragmentToDisplay = new homeFragment();
    } else if (ItemId == R.id.led_menu) {
        FragmentToDisplay = new ledFragment();
    } else if (ItemId == R.id.pin_menu) {

    } else if (ItemId == R.id.ecran_menu) {

    }

    if (FragmentToDisplay != null) {
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentLayout, FragmentToDisplay);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    Log.i("Display something", "Display Home");
}}
```

and here the code of my Fragment:

```
public class ledFragment extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.led_layout, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: add vs replace...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentLayout, FragmentToDisplay);
```

with:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentLayout, FragmentToDisplay);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Fragments Transactions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions) documentation you can have a better overview of the `add()` and `replace()`

Answer (score 0):

this method adds the fragment to the fragment and the remaining fragment continues to work.if you don't want to do this.

```
if (FragmentToDisplay != null) {
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentLayout, FragmentToDisplay);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

try this method

```
if (FragmentToDisplay != null) {
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentLayout, FragmentToDisplay);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
```